# Foreign key constraint not working in sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

- python version: 3.8.10
- `sqlite3.version`: 2.6.0
- `sqlite3.sqlite_version`: 3.31.1

I have two tables: `blocklist` and `blocklist_reasons`. See below:

```
blocklist_reasons
id | reason
--------------------------
1  | Source not supported

blocklist
id | link            | reason
-----------------------------
1  | https://mega.nz | 1
```

`blocklist.reason` references `blocklist_reasons.id`, so a foreign key constraint is set up.

However, I can insert any number I want and it will still accept it, which is strange:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO blocklist(link, reason) VALUES ('https://example.com', 2);
sqlite> -- No problems eventhough there is no row in blocklist_reasons with ID 2???
sqlite> SELECT * FROM blocklist;
1|https://mega.nz|1
2|https://example.com|2
```

I was able to reproduce this problem with the following code:

```sql
-- Create reasons table and add one reason with ID 1
CREATE TABLE blocklist_reasons(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    reason TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO blocklist_reasons(reason) VALUES ('Source not supported');
SELECT * FROM blocklist_reasons;
1|Source not supported

-- Create blocklist table and insert row with reason ID set as ID 2 without errors
CREATE TABLE blocklist(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    link TEXT NOT NULL,
    reason INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (reason) REFERENCES blocklist_reasons(id)
);
INSERT INTO blocklist(link, reason) VALUES ('https://mega.nz', 2);
SELECT * FROM blocklist;
1|https://mega.nz|2
```

You can see that I inserted a row with the `reason` column set to `2` and it worked fine, eventhough there is no row in the `blocklist_reasons` table with an ID of 2. Why isn't the foreign key constraint raising an error?

Comment: Yeah, see my answer, that was the problem. I find it stupid that you have to explicitly enable such feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I have to *ENABLE* foreign key checking. In my opinion stupid but alright. Everytime you start a database connection (not a cursor connection but a database connection), run the following command:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

This enables the constraint.